# Merge two tables - "abort due to constraint violation"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: tableA and tableB. Both have the same columns but with different information. I aam trying to merge them by using

```
 INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM tableB
```

but then I am presented with an error message: "Abort due to constraint violation". I am using SQLite expert personal. Am I doing something wrong with my query?

Suggestions?

Comment: Show us the schema: select * from sqlite_master;

Comment: Are you sure that there are no unique contraints that will be violated by the merge?

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of "*" to name all the colums.

```
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT tableB.xyz FROM tableB
```